# NGXS dispatch-decorator plugin not working with withLatestFromOperator

Tags: angular, state, state-management, ngxs

Im using NGXS as my state management along with its plugin 
https://github.com/ngxs-labs/dispatch-decorator

I have the following code on my component:

```
this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  tap((params: ParamMap) => {
    this.facade.initializeForm();
  }),
  switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
    const id = +params.get('id');
    return of(this.facade.viewOrder(id));
  }),
  withLatestFrom(this.facade.currentlyViewedDelivery$),

).subscribe((delivery) => {
  console.log('DELIVERY', delivery);
});
```

this is my the viewOrder():

```
  @Dispatch() viewOrder = (id: number) => new OrderAction.View(id);
```

However, the results on my subscribe tells me that currentlyViewedDelivery$ returns a value of null. When I tried delay() operator before withLatestFrom() it works. It gives me idea that the dispatch action is not finished yet. However, when I tried a normal dispatching using Store it works without using delay(). What might be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but the `@Dispatch` decorator shouldn't be used like that.

What does this plugin do? Basically it overrides your method, take its return value (it has to be a single action, `Observable` or `Promise`), unwraps it (subscribes or resolves a `Promise`) and invokes `dispatch` under the hood for you.

I assume that the `View` action handler does some asynchronous job, that's why you see the updated state value when you pipe with the `delay` operator.

Frankly speaking you have to listen to the `View` action completion, see the below code:

```js
this.route.paramMap
  .pipe(
    tap((params: ParamMap) => {
      this.facade.initializeForm();
    }),
    switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
      const id = +params.get('id');
      this.facade.viewOrder(id);
      return this.actions$.pipe(ofActionSuccessful(OrderAction.View), take(1));
    }),
    withLatestFrom(this.facade.currentlyViewedDelivery$)
  )
  .subscribe(delivery => {
    console.log('DELIVERY', delivery);
  });
```

Where `actions$` is an injected `Actions` class.

If you prefer using facades then you can just move this logic to some facade method and call this method something else :)

Comment: I will try this and let you know :) Thank you very much.  I did not think about using action$ :)